# How interpret this notation.

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $f : M \to \mathbb{R}$ be $C^{\infty}$. For $v \in M_p=\pi^{-1}(p)=\{\text{fibre of M at p}\}$ I want to conclude that

$$f_{*}(v)=df(v)_{f(p)} \in  \mathbb{R}_{f(p)}$$

---

> **Question**

I don't know how to proceed here because I am thinking $df(v)$ as the derivation $v$ evaluated at $f$ but I think that this definition only applies with $v \in T_pM$. And for the push forward $f_{*}$ I am understanding $f_{*}(v)$ as the equivalence class of $f \circ v$ so the above statement doesn't make sense if $df(v)_{f(p)}$ is not a equivalence class that clearly is not since by hypothesis $df(v)_{f(p)} \in  \mathbb{R}_{f(p)}$.

**Note**:This is taken from Spivak's A comprehensive introduction to Differential Geometry volume 1 chapter 4.

Comment: Well $[f\circ v]\in T_{f(p)}\mathbb{R}$, and this is what is meant by $\mathbb{R}_{f(p)}$ I guess.

Comment: Well in Spivak's book it says that $\mathbb{R}_p$ is when you move all the space $\mathbb{R}$ in $p$

Comment: I guess you mean "by $p$". But that's indeed precisely what the tangent space at $p$ is. The tangent space of $\mathbb{R}$ (as a manifold) is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$ (as a vector space), and since it's located at $p$, moving everything by $p$ gives you the $\mathbb{R}$ at the point $p$ (whatever this means, by the way) and thus $T_{f(p)}\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Ok so I should interpret $f_{*}$ as a equivalence class of a smooth curve $v$ and a smooth function $f$ with the relation that we define when we want to define the tangent space right?

Comment: I'm still in blank of what do I have to prove and how to do it

Comment: @B.Pasternak What can be done?