# How to prove this formula involving diferentials

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $f:M^{n} \to N^{m}$, and suppose that $(x,U)$ and $(y,V)$ are coordinate systems around $p$ and $f(p)$, respectively, then I want to conclude that for $g:N \to \mathbb{R}$

$$\frac{\partial(g \circ f)}{\partial x^{i}}(p)=\sum_{j=1}^{m}\frac{\partial(g )}{\partial y^{j}}(f(p))·\frac{\partial(y^{j} \circ f)}{\partial x^{i}}(p)$$

---

> **Attempt**

1. Given that we know that

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^{i}}(p)=\sum_{j=1}^{m}\frac{\partial f}{\partial y^{j}}·\frac{\partial y^{j}}{\partial x^{i}}$$

we perform the following

$$\frac{\partial(g \circ f)}{\partial x^{i}}(p)=\sum_{j=1}^{m}\frac{\partial (g \circ f)}{\partial y^{j}}·\frac{\partial y^{j}}{\partial x^{i}}=\sum_{j=1}^{m}\frac{\partial g}{\partial y^{j}}(f(p))·\frac{\partial f}{\partial y^{j}}·\frac{\partial y^{j}}{\partial x^{i}}$$

2. We have that

$$\frac{\partial(g \circ f)}{\partial x^{i}}(p)=D_i((g \circ f) \circ x^{-1})(x(p))$$

I don't know which trick I can use from here,the thing is that I want to use the chain rule as Spivak does on page 38. I was trying to do the following

$$D_i((g \circ f) \circ x^{-1})(x(p))=D_i([(g \circ f)\circ f^{-1} \circ y] \circ [y^{-1} \circ f \circ x^{-1}])(x(p))$$

but is not quite right since it doesn't conduce to the desire identity and i don't know if $f$ has an inverse.

---

> **Questions**

I think I have something wrong because I didn't get what I want. And I don't know if I was o the right track. Can someone help me to prove this result please?

**Note:** This is taken from Spivak's A comprehensive introduction to Differential Geometry volume 1 chapter 4

Thanks in advance

Comment: Then what can be done?

Comment: Your "Attempt" has a bunch of $\frac{\partial y^j}{\partial x^i}$ in it. Surely that can't make sense; what is the dependence of $y^j$ on $x^i$ meant to be? They're coordinate systems around different points.

Comment: Ok so can you provide a well performed proof of this ? I mean the formula in my post :)

Comment: It is suppose that $\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{i}}$ is a vector field sending $p \to \frac{\partial}{\partial x^{i}} \big{|}_p$

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan I have edited my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This (the first part of the first exercise in the stated chapter of Spivak) is one of those questions where all the work is in figuring out how the formalism works rather than engaging with any actual ideas :-).

By definition we have

$$\frac{\partial (g\circ f)}{\partial x^i}(p)=D_i(g\circ f\circ x^{-1})(x(p)).$$

We're going to want to work with partial derivatives for the functions we're composing, so let's go via $\Bbb{R}^m$ and rewrite that:

$$=D_i(g\circ y^{-1}\circ y\circ f\circ x^{-1})(x(p)).$$

Now apply the ordinary chain rule for partial derivatives in euclidean space:

$$=\sum_j D_i(y\circ f\circ x^{-1})^j(x(p))\cdot D_j(g\circ y^{-1})(y\circ f\circ x^{-1}(x(p)).$$

Simplify a little:

$$=\sum_j D_i(y^j\circ f\circ x^{-1})(x(p))\cdot D_j(g\circ y^{-1})(y(f(p)).$$

But now each of those factors is just (by definition) a partial derivative:

$$=\sum_j \frac{\partial (y^j\circ f)}{\partial x^i}(p)\cdot \frac{\partial g}{\partial y^j}(f(p)).$$

And we're done (though it happens that I have the factors the opposite way around from Spivak).

Comment: Thanks :) let me check it just give me some time  :)

Comment: Can you help me with this one http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1747033/how-interpret-this-notation ?